# Schafer & Sons 84697 spinet

Tags: piano

[image][image]My grandparents passed away recently and left me my grandmother's Schafer & Son's spinet piano. I live in NE Colorado and it is located in their home that is being readied for sale in Broken Arrow, OK area. I have to move it out here asap, but have no info on it except some photos my Aunt sent me and a number she said is the serial number: 84697. After doing some research, I found out that several manufacturers produced Vern Schafer's pianos and that particular serial number came up under both Schimmel (1964) and Samich (1986). I know my grandmother had this piano when I was very young and had thought she had it before I was born (1983), but seeing as she's no longer around to ask, I'm here hoping someone can shed some light on my query. I need to know when the piano was manufactured for certain in order to set up the move. I have more pics with measurements, but they are blurry.

Comment: It's not clear what your query is. Could you edit this to include a question?

Comment: What is the significance of providing the manufacture date of a piano in order to ship it? It seems irrelevant,

Comment: Ask the manufacturers, if they're still in business. If they're not, then the movers  won't be able to confirm or deny any date you give them. This sort of question isn't really what the site is set up for, and I can't offer a better place. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is as follows:

The movers are probably asking for manufacturing date for insurance reasons. The instrument could, possibly, be a very valuable 16th century antique. There could be a bit of understandable confusion here. The word spinet often indicates a very different instrument (smaller harpsicord) from "spinet piano" which is a smaller sized piano. Purely for insurance valuation, these kinds of smaller pianos are not very sought after today and does not catch very high values in sales but probably has a larger sentimental value for you.

Personally I would simply answer 1964 to the movers.